# Intrepretation of よく

Tags: grammar, adverbs

A sentence from Japanesepod101, with the official translation.

> 赤のブドウも緑のブドウもよく搾｛しぼ｝るとワインやジュースになります。
>   Both red and green grapes are good squeezed and turned into wine or juice.

Their translation of よく as good (i.e. the grapes good for being squeezed) doesn't seem right. To me よく should be referring to 搾る (i.e. if the grapes are well/properly squeezed, they become wine or juice). Here I have interpreted the と as "if/when". Was my interpretation correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**よく** can only reference **搾る**, because the adjective precedes the verb. In English, the adjective must be translated as **well**. The inaccurate English translation may occlude your understanding.
The present (or: non-past) tense, here of the verb **搾る**, together with the particle **と** do indeed express a conditional relationship (*if*).

Comment: Thanks. I suppose due to the conditional relationship (と), よく also cannot mean "often" in this sentence?

Comment: I don't believe there's such a connection.